# Array using one of the columns fetched as the array key - getting error message "unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW"

Tags: php, arrays, key

I'm trying to create an array using one of the columns fetched as the array key, but I'm getting the error message `unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW`

```
$students = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) { 
    $students[$row['first_name']] => $row['last_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=>` should be replaced with `=`

```
$students[$row['first_name']] = $row['last_name'];
```

Comment: Does it ring logic to you, that the OP is trying to equate `first_name` to `last_name` ? that does not make sense

Comment: I believe this is doing what I need - setting the column 'first_name' as the array key for 'last_name' - right?

Comment: If he was assigning in an array, eg array('key' => 'val'), then `=>` would be correct, also if he was in a foreach loop.

But he's not, he's assigning a value to a array key (by array variable), so he needs `=`

Comment: @ChayaCooper exactly this.

Comment: Yes Chaya, this is what you need. :)

Comment: :-D @AdrianCrepaz - Would you mind clarifying what you said about  assigning in an array, etc.? I think that might be helpful for me to keep in mind

Answer (score 0):

```
$students = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) { 
    $students=array($row['first_name'] => $row['last_name']);
}
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I was looking for - it's using the proper column as the key, but I believe it's creating subarrays. But I'll need to use that for something else ;-)